# pgjdbc-ng throws mysterious ServiceLoader error

Tags: postgresql, hikaricp, pgjdbc-ng

I'm getting a very weird error in my logs. This just started happening randomly and was not triggered by a version upgrade of anything.

```
2019-08-23 14:49:41.150 ccleves-mac-mini.local com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource 7177 INFO  HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2019-08-23 14:49:41.150 ccleves-mac-mini.local com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource 7177 INFO  HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-08-23 14:49:41.150 ccleves-mac-mini.local com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource 7177 INFO  HikariPool-3 - Starting...
2019-08-23 14:49:41.676 ccleves-mac-mini.local com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool 7703 ERROR HikariPool-3 - Error thrown while acquiring connection from data source
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.nextElement(CompoundEnumeration.java:59)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.system.procs.Procs.loadDecoderProc(Procs.java:107)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.system.procs.Procs.loadNamedBinaryCodec(Procs.java:83)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.types.BaseType.<init>(BaseType.java:46)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.types.BaseType.<init>(BaseType.java:50)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.types.SharedRegistry.<init>(SharedRegistry.java:123)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver.lambda$connect$0(PGDriver.java:106)
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1127)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver.lambda$connect$1(PGDriver.java:106)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.system.BasicContext.init(BasicContext.java:303)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDirectConnection.init(PGDirectConnection.java:276)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.ConnectionUtil.createConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:205)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.ConnectionUtil.createConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:165)
    at com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver.connect(PGDriver.java:113)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
```

Even weirder: It happens when I am developing the app in Eclipse. If I stop the app and then restart in Eclipse, it happens. If I close out Eclipse entirely and reopen it, the problem goes away and all connections open fine.

If I look at the connections on the Postgres server I don't see anything out of place. When it works, 10 connections get opened. When it fails, then just one.

Comment: Can you show datasource configuration?

Comment: I have similar problems, sometime StackOverflow, sometime NoSuchElement, sometime OutOfBoundException.
And sometime it work.
If you find a solution, I would be more than happy to have it

Comment: @LucDUZAN See https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng/issues/417 It's a bug. The workaround is to do a query on startup. There's probably a race condition and this gets around it.

Comment: For my part, I have issues because both slick (a scala "orm") and my code where creating a connection at the same time.
Building a common data-source first and sharing it between them solved my problem!
But no I am using an other driver with slick (official one seems faster)... and I use pgjdbc-ng only for async listener